# Signed document retrieval and envelope creation using Docusign API

Tags: iframe, docusignapi

We have been checking DocuSign APIs through your sandbox for the integration with our App. Currently we are facing issues where we are stuck.

1. Would you please advise how we can retrieve the signed document through API? We found that once we signed a document the sigining URL seems to be expired and we couldn't find any other URL or anything to retrieve the signed document from our App programmatically?
2. We are trying to integrate DocuSign with our hybrid mobile app and we saw in your documentation that you are not recommending iFrame. But if we need to implement the functionality for adding signature fields, or text boxes on the fly by using your APIs, we need to have the events in our page for those and we should use iFrame in such cases.

   So please let me know whether there is any other way through which you are providing us controls to be dragged to the envelope (like control palette) when we take it in our app?

Comment: _"we saw in your documentation that you are not recommending iFrame"_ Which documentation are you referring to?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note that whilst there may be Docusign users here, and related questions are welcome, this is not an official Docusign support channel. Your audience does not own a sandbox and does not work for this firm.

Comment: @halfer Hi, i'm very sorry that i even used that phrase, my bad, actually just copy pasted the same question from docusign support community, forgot to clear that word out.

Comment: OK, if you have cross-posted, please add a link here and there indicating the location of the other copy. It is helpful for readers to be able to check cross-posted copies before posting, so they do not make a wasted effort when answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the documents in an envelope using the [getEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) api.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

---

For integrating DocuSign into your mobile app look at Docusign [embedded sending](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSending). You can find more information for optimizing embedded workflows [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#OptimizingUX)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response  i tried the way you have mentioned, and i am able to get the file as an SplFileObject object which can be downloaded, but the thing is that, is there any way that i can get the url of the signed document rather than the file itself so that i can embed the signed document url into an iframe. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: It is not possible to generate a link to access the document using the API. Users have to login to Docusign to view signed documents. They can also view by clicking the links they receive in the email from Docusign, depending on the autentication settings set up by the sender.